# How to pass both a Function and Prop to an onClick Event in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I only see examples of people passing two functions but nothing on a prop and function simultaneously. Let's say I want the pass `onClick={props.tested}` (prop) and `onClick={divTested}` (function) at the same time. How do I do this??

Comment: Is this what you are looking for ? onclick={(e) => divTested(props.tested)}

Comment: By the way, this looks like a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: "*I want to pass prop and function at the same time?*" - this makes no sense. Notice that a prop like `props.tested` is also just a function. If you have multiple functions to call, just do `onClick={ (e) => { props.tested(e); divTested(e); } }`

Comment: @subodhkalika I tried this and it doesn't work and just turns my entire application blank/white. I've been searching for a solution to this prob for like 2 hours now to no avail. You'd think it would be pretty basic..

Comment: You can show us what you've tried

Comment: I am sorry but it's not clear in the question of what are you trying to achieve. If you can tell what you are trying to achieve, there can be multiple solutions provided.

Comment: @Bergi This is also another solution I tried and it also does not work and turns my app blank/white.. I tried it again and it still doesn't work..

Comment: I thought I was clear. I want to pass both a prop from a parent component to a child component AND invoke a function when an onClick event is started. When I test both the function and props on their own, they work completely fine. But I have no idea how to add both of them to the same click event. @subodhkalika

Comment: @TheLonerCoder What is the error you are getting when the app "turns blank"?

Comment: `invoke a function when an onClick event is started`. Where is this onClick event happening? Child or parent?

Comment: @TheLonerCoder Maybe the prop is optional and not (always) being passed, so you need `(e) => { props.tested?.(e); divTested(e) }`? You really need to give us a [mcve] with the complete code to demonstrate the problem. Please [edit] your question.

Comment: Would be helpful if you can provide a code structure and help us understand.

Comment: @subodhkalika it's happening in the child component on a div element.

Comment: So you want to call a function passed from Parent on this onCLick event ?

Answer (score 1):

Although I rarely see this done, you can indeed add properties to a function, and pass that "function with properties" into another function that is aware of those properties:

```js
let functionWithProperties = function(a, b)
{
  return a + b;
}

// Add Properties to the function:
functionWithProperties.a = 5;
functionWithProperties.b = 10;

function doSomethingWithFunctionWithProperties(func)
{
  return func(func.a,func.b);
}

// Pass function with properties into another function
// that is aware of those properties:
let output = doSomethingWithFunctionWithProperties(functionWithProperties);

console.log(output); // 15
```

Comment: Sweet! I never knew you can add Properties to the function

Comment: This is not what the OP wants.